# how to select recently inserted data into mysql database?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with  two columns:

```
#MY_DATA
* ID
* DATA
```

How can I write a select query to get recently inserted data (like STACK)?

Comment: Is ID an identity field?

Comment: this is mysql. just i want LIFO based selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select data from MY_DATA where ID=(select max ID from MY_DATA)
```

If you want multiple rows then

```
Select data from MY_DATA order by ID desc limit X
```

**X** is a positive number

Comment: That would only give one record, would it not?

Comment: with the word **recently** I thought he wants just the last one.

Comment: Looks like it won't work anyway, though, as he's using random IDs rather than auto-incrementing ones. Which, as I just noticed, means `LAST_INSERT_ID()` won't work, either.

Comment: *he's using random ID* but he did not mentioned it :(

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777967/how-to-select-recently-inserted-data-into-mysql-database/11777993#comment15642752_11778017. ":(" indeed.

Answer (score 0):

is your ID field automatically generated (e.g. autoincrement in mysql or secuence in Oracle)? 
if yes, then just sort it:

```
select * from my_table order by id desc
```

if not, there is no standard way. the best way is to add some timestamp field, store current datetime value for new records and then order by this field.

Comment: my ID field is randomly generated unique id. just i want LIFO (Last in first out)